# Can a webworker capture touch input?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Can a web worker thread capture input events on canvas? That is touch/click events occurring within the canvas object on an HTML page. I would then message those events to the main thread.

Comment: No, it can't. But why would you want it to?

Comment: Thanks! I thought it could be an optimizan since my main thread is already quite heavy.

Comment: JavaScript is strict about having UI related code only in the main thread. I would rather suggest to move the heavy parts already in the ui thread to a worker. If there are heavy computations that must be processed after a button click, then you simply add a click handler in the main thread, which would just call `worker.postMessage`. There is no way to get around this step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the answer is no per the conversation on this thread.